# Slow Workflow with RTX 3060

Tags: rendering, gpu, performance, hardware

I am quite desperate, because I just bought a new laptop (XMG CORE 17 - E21qzj FHD i7
16GB 1TBSSD **RTX3060** W10H) and I tried to adjust all the settings, but it is just so slow.

Right now I am trying to model a body-suit, but it just takes ages to even move one plane in edit mode, both in EEVE and Cycles and both without even showing the rendered view.

I really fell in love with blender, but right now its complicated.

[image: blender preferences][image: monitoring_quile_using_blender_cpu]
[image: monitoring_quile_using_blender_gpu] [image: NVIDA Settings_1][image: NVIDA_Settings_2] [image: project]

Here is the file (565 MB): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ryDi1LNruFc7doZIzxrzS-Lhhz7EQN3f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello! That is weird, I have a 3070 and it works perfect. A 3060 should be more than enough. How large is your file and how many vertices does your model have? Your settings look fine to me. Can you also explain how and when it is going slow?

Comment: The RTX3060 will speed up *rendering* (when using eevee and cycles) but won't help the viewport significantly (eg. for modeling). Seems like you added several particle systems on top of the character which is most likely your issue. Try to disable them and see whether that helps to add your plane.

Comment: Thank you already for your answers, great how fast this works. @DarkSoul: So my file size is 565MB. ,

Comment: @brockmann  When you say "disable" do you mean hide? I already hid all the other things, and also disabled it for rendering. Is there any chance, to make my workflow faster? I dont know, but I just have the feeling that my computer is so slow with a lot of things :(

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your scene, suggest save a new version of your file and try to delete all extra tiny bits (like particle systems) until you figured out the issue *or* provide the file so we can have a look. By judging the specifications your machine isn't that slow but not incredibly fast either. If you'd like to proof the performance (for rendering), run a benchmark: https://opendata.blender.org/ or just use cinebench.

Comment: 500mb isnt that huge. Your computer seems fine to me, but I think there is something with that scene. But as brockmann suggested. Make a backup and remove all your hair/particles and see if that helps.

Comment: I think 565MB for a single character with ~250k verts IS huge. I have a char with 1million verts (multires) and file is 44MB + 10MB textures. Maybe it's the shapekeys? Blender's Rain char has ~250 MB - Anyway, findings: there is a mirror modifier on the char, it doubles all vertices. Remove it. The node setup for the bodysuit (normal map + bump node) is wrong. But even w/o it there is a strange shading and sculpting doesn't work?! I removed custom normal data, disabled Autosmooth. Still looks blocky. The Rigify armature has all control bones doubled?! What is the weird "plane" on the left?

Comment: @Blunder I think it could be because I imported it from character creator and then I also subdivided it. I started Blender only a month ago, so I am still very unknowledgeable about the consquences of certain moves. Thank you so much for all your help, I will try everything out tomorrow :) I feel a lot more optimistic than today morning :)